# Computing Similarities between Vectors

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, predictive-models

I am given a $m \times n$ matrix $M$ which consists of integers, with the majority of the entries missing. I am interesting in figuring out which pairs of rows are "similar" in some sense. So far I've looked into cosine similarity and Pearson correlation but neither really give me the right kind of results I'm looking into. In particular, one weakness is when I wish to compute the similarity between rows $a$ and $b$, both of them only use the entries in rows $a$ and $b$ to compute similarity, which is perhaps not optimal. What other similarity metrics are there which people use?

The exact context I am using is ratings of TV shows, in that the $m$ rows are TV shows and the $n$ columns are user ratings. The standard approaches such as collaborative filtering simply fill in missing entries to the matrix, which is not exactly what I need here. I want something such as "because you liked show X, you are likely to enjoy shows Y,Z,...".

Comment: You clearly should try association rule mining.